# Get instance of another tabBar item

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to set a property of tab(0) at tab(1).

This is what I am trying to do at tab(1). But it's getting a crash

```
FirstTabViewController *firstTabVC = (FirstTabViewController*)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
firstTabVC.property = newProperty;
```

`[UINavigationController setProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a25a80`
tab(0) has a navigationController if that helps. I have synthesize the property on tab(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this.

```
UINavigationController *firstTabNC = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
firstTabViewController *firstTabVC = (FirstTabViewController*)[[firstTabNC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[firstTabVC setProperty:newProperty];
```